# sql to nhibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I need to convert this SQL query to nhibernate

```
declare @i int set @i=2
while (@i>0)
begin 
insert into #tmp_table3 (id , descr , RangeType , createdate )
select  * from AgeRanges as ar where AgeRangeID in (
select AgeRangeID as id from AgeRangeDetails where  agerangeid in
(select AgeRangeID from agerangedetails group by AgeRangeID having COUNT(AgeRangeID)=2)  
and agestart =(select AgeStart from #tmp_table2 where id=@i)
and AgeEnd = (select AgeEnd from #tmp_table2 where id=@i)
and Payment = (select Payment from #tmp_table2 where id=@i)
group by AgeRangeID)
and AgeRangeType=0
and AgeRangeID<>5 
set @i=@i-1
end
select id from #tmp_table3 where id in
(select id from #tmp_table3 group by id having COUNT(id)=2) group by id
```

can someone help me to do this.
thanks

Comment: This looks like quite a bit of work. Can you please tell us which part you actually struggle with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a custom bit of SQL, it has a while loop, tmp tables and variables. For this reason you are only going to be able to either create a Stored Procedure or use a named query.

a) create a Stored procedure and call it using:-

```
session.CreateSqlQuery("exe sp_name")...
```

[more details](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/using-stored-procedures-with-nhibernate.html)...

b) create a named query in mapping and call it like this:-

```
session.GetNamedQuery("MyNamedQuery")...
```

[more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576242/creating-class-for-stored-procedure-returning-data-from-multiple-tables)...